# How to perform Authentication and Authorization in Xamarin.Forms ?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

My authentication and authorization knowledge are based on web background where all I had to was to use **"Authorize" attribute** **(ASP.NET)** attribute , or maybe creating a **"middleware"** and assign it to a controller **(Laravel)**.

What is the best practice of Authentication and Authorization in Xamarin.Forms using MVVM approach (with example) ?

Do Android and IOS share the same implementation or there will be platform tweaks ?

Comment: Have you seen [Xamarin's Authentication Info](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/)? You do not need to use platform specific code to do authentication/authorization.

Comment: Thanks it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to authenticate the user through Asp.Net WebApi I always use such template of code:

```
    using( client = new HttpClient () ) {
        ...
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authHeaderValue);
    }
```

It can be made in PCL because HttpClient is shared for both Android and iOS.
Also, you should read this article:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/rest/